# how to get shell script output into c structure variable

Tags: c, shell

I need to collect shell script output into my c program linked list node, I have tried popen() also. But typecast error occur there. I need this in my project.
please help......

Comment: You should show your code and then we could perhaps help you with the reason for the typecast error. Popen() is the right approach.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  When you ask a question, especially one like this, you need to show that you've put some effort into solving your problem, if only by posting an SSCCE ([Simple, Self-Contained, Complete (Compiling) Example](http://sscce.org/)) based on your code.  It should show what you've tried, and you should detail what is going wrong and what you want it to do.  In this case, if you've got a compilation problem, it's OK to drop the 'compiling' part, just about.  But it needs to be mostly compilable.  Platform (O/S) and compiler information help too.

Answer (score 1):

What did you try with `popen`? This works as expected:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buf[BUFSIZ];
    FILE *fp = popen("sh script", "r");

    while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp) != NULL)
        printf("Received: '%s'\n", buf);

    pclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```